# How to Retrieve Information from FormData

Tags: javascript, ajax, express

I'm uploading a picture on change from an input, and I want to send the information to my database.

Apart from the picture, I need to get the id of my item and because I'm working on a picture (formData) I appended also this information (id).

```
var promoId = 37
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('promoId', promoId)

console.log('formData -', formData.get("promoId")) // Gives me the correct number
```

The problem is that I'm trying to retrieve it on the back-end but is coming as 'undefined'

This is what I have tried so far.

```
AJAX
$.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: `/api/Upload-second-promo`,
     crossDomain: true,
     data: formData,
     cache: false,
     processData: false,
     contentType: false,
     enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
     mimeType: 'multipart/form-data',
})

BACK-END
router.post('/Upload-second-promo', function(req, res) {
     promoId = req.body.promoId // undefined
     promoId = req.promoId // undefined
     promoId = req.query.promoId // undefined
}
```

How do you get the information out of formData on the back-end?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using express 4. You can use [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) middleware in order to get your data into `req.body` property.

For example: (Extracted from official doc)

```js
var express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

var app = express()

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.use(function (req, res) {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
  res.write('you posted:\n')
  res.end(JSON.stringify(req.body, null, 2))
})
```